# Datadog regex parser rule not applied to logs

Tags: datadog

I have written a regex rule in Grok parser to parse the log url paths. While it says the patterns matches in the sample section, but when checking the live tail i couldn't see the rules getting applied correctly. Please can you help on this.

regex used: parseurl %{regex("^([\/][\w\d\-\/]*([a-z][\w\d\-][^\w\d\-\.]))|[\/]"):http.url_details.patternx}.*

Sample log patterns: Input: /abcd/efgh?13224 Expected: /abcd/efgh

PS: Iam new to Datadog

Comment: What regex syntax is that? it doesn't look like Grok patterns

Comment: I'm using online utility https://regexr.com by gskinner to create the regex and using it in grok parser.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is JavaScript regex. There are many kinds of regex. Grok regex has a specific syntax; it won't work with arbitrary regex engines.

You need to use Grok syntax rather than JS or PCRE etc. This tool can help you build and test your expressions. https://grokconstructor.appspot.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have any suggestions on any tools for building patterns specific to grok parser of Datadog?